# MBR to GPT Conversion of existing RHEL 6 system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel

I have got RHEL 6 running on MBR (Master Boot Record), management is done using fdisk and parted commands. I would like to know the steps or procedure to convert existing system to GPT (GUID Partition Table) can be managed using (gdisk and gparted) for large disk support.

Also wants to make sure whether system has got normal BIOS is EFI BIOS. Is there any command for that?

And if system have got normal BIOS how to implement GPT?

Comment: Did you try any of the thousands of suggestions retured by google for [linux convert mbr gpt](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+convert+mbr+gpt)?

Comment: I have tried couple of suggestions from Google but crashed the test system. will be really grateful to you if you can recommend any particular blog/web for that. Many thanks.